# Query users that might interacted with on same category

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to do a query to list all the users that may interacted with each other on the same category with a note. Basically, everyone that made a note on a category that the specific user made a note on. How can be done?

Let's say the USER ID is 3, that left a note (note_10):

```
ID  U   CATEGORY  NOTE
1   3   5         'note_10'
2   1   3         'note_11'
3   2   5         'note_12'
4   5   2         'note_13'
5   6   5         'note_14'
6   7   5         'note_15'
```

**Expected results:**

```
U
2
6
7
```

ID number 2, 6, and 7 has posted on the same category.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a self-join with some filtering:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tt
     on tt.category = t.category and
        tt.note = 'note_10';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=695cd137d6f393da2e93e5201b94186c) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want to filter out the original user, you can use:

```
from t join
     t tt
     on tt.category = t.category and
        tt.note = 'note_10' and
        tt.id <> t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t.u
from mytable t
where 
    t.u <> 3
    and exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.u = 3 and t1.category= t.category)
```

This gives you all users that posted on any category user 3 posted on.

This might generate duplicates in a given user has several categories in common with user `3` - if you want to avoid that, you can use `select distinct` instead.

Another option is window functions:

```
select u
from (
    select u, count(*) filter(where u = 3) over(partition by category) cnt
    from mytable
) t
where u <> 3 and cnt > 0
```